# Matching different patterns by regexp

Tags: regex, perl

I am a beginner in regexp and I need to match something like :

```
Tab[0]hash/0-786541/value : 12
```

I tried lot of things but in doesn't match.

For example :

```
^([\w\[\*\]]*[\w\/(0-9)\-(0-9){8})\/]\w)\s*:\s*
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: What parts do you need to extract from it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use below code.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$str="Tab[0]hash/0-786541/value : 12";

        if ($str =~ /(\w)*\[(\d)\](\w)*\/(\d)-([0-8])*\/(\w)*(\s)\:(\d)*/)
        {
                print "matched\n";
        }
        else
        {
                print "not matched\n";
        }


(\w)*: [a-zA-Z] followed by zero\more times of [a-zA-Z]

\[   : \[ escape [ so that perl interpreter not to think it as start of charecter class

(\d) : followed bu any digit

\]   : \] escape ] so that perl interpreter not to think it as end of charecter class

(\w)*: [a-zA-Z] followed by zero\more times of [a-zA-Z]

\/   : escape / so that perl interpreter not to think it as end on regular expression

(\d) : followed by a digit [0-9]

 -   : followed by -

([0-8])*: followed by [0-8] (zero\more times)

\/   : escape / so that perl interpreter not to think it as end on regular expression

(\w)*: [a-zA-Z] followed by zero\more times of [a-zA-Z]

(\s) : followed by a space

\:   : followed by a colon

(\d)*: followed by digits [0-9] (zero\more times)
```

Comment: `\w` is NOT equivalent to `[a-zA-Z]`, it means `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the string need be parsed by `/` and `:` here are some basic ways to parse

```
my $str = 'Tab[0]hash/0-786541/value : 12';
```

Using [split](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html)

```
my @parts = split /\/|:/, $str;
```

the string is split on either `/` or `:`, as `split` takes a full regex for its pattern specification inside `/.../`.  We can also clean out most spaces while matching

```
my @parts = split /\s*(?:\/|:)\s*/, $str;
```

what returns the list with elements without surrounding spaces (except for trailing spaces, at the end of the string). The [non-capturing group](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Non-capturing-groupings) `(?:...)` is used since with `()` the delimiters are captured and returned as well.

Using regex

```
my @parts = $str =~ m{ \s* ([^/:]+) \s* }gx;
```

matching anything that is not `/` or `:`, one or more times. The `/g` modifier makes it continue until the string is exhausted, matching all occurrences of the pattern and returning the list of matches that are captured by `()`.

I use `{}` delimiters to not have to escape `/`, and then `m{}` is needed. With the `/x` modifier we may freely use spaces, newlines, and comments inside (they are not matched), for readability.

Then we can separate the number

```
my @num = pop @parts;
```

in both cases.

This can be parsed by more specific patterns but for that we really should know what needs to be extracted. One normally makes use of "landmark" patterns in a string, to be able to form precise match targets, and of knowledge of *what* is needed from it, rather than specifying *every* element.

---

If the shown string represents typical lines in a file

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $file = '...';
open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Can't open $file: $!";

while (<$fh>) 
{
    my @parts = m{\s*([^/:]+)\s*}g;    #/
    my $num = pop @parts;
    print "@parts -- $num\n";

    # Reassemble (up to extra spaces), perhaps for a check
    # my $orig_str = join('/', @parts) . " : $num";
}
```

(that `#/` is there only to turn off the wrong syntax highlight by the markup)

Answer (score 0):

```
 my $str = 'Tab[0]hash/0-786541/value : 12';

 if($str=~m{^(\w)*\[.*?\]([^\/]*)/([^\/]*)/([^\:]*)\s*\:\s*([^\d\w]*)\n?})
 {
      print "Matches...\n" 
 }
```

Just try this: